# SqlAlchemy. Cannot add two Foreign keys. There are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm new in sqlalchemy. I need to create two foreign keys in child (Student) class.
Now I can do something like this:

```
>>> student_one = Student(name='Sam')
>>> student_two = Student(name='Nick')
>>> group_one = Group(group_number='ST141', students=[student_one, student_two], senior_student=student_one)
>>> group_one.students
>>> group_one.senior_student
```

That would be correct. And now I want to have `senior_student_of` field in `Student` table. I've tried a lot of ways to do something with but couldn't add it.
This is my code:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    group_number = Column(String(10), nullable=True, default='')
    study_hours = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=True)
    lab_studies = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=True)
    pract_studies = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=True)

    curator = relationship('Tutor', backref='tutors', lazy='dynamic')
    students = relationship('Student', backref='groups', lazy='dynamic')
    senior_student = relationship('Student', uselist=False, lazy='joined')

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.group_number


class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'students'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    surname = Column(String(20), nullable=True, default='', )
    name = Column(String(20), nullable=True, default='')
    patronymic = Column(String(20), nullable=True, default='')
    absences = Column(Integer, nullable=True, default=0)
    undone_labs = Column(Integer, nullable=True, default=0)
    unready_labs = Column(Integer, nullable=True, default=0)

    group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
    group = relationship(Group)

    # This don't work
    senior_student_of_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
    senior_student_of = relationship(Group)
```

Always get an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Group.students - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'f
oreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.
```

Finally, I'll need to get `student_one.senior_student_of` correctly and see  `ST141` there.
Couldn't search right solution. Thank you for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
group = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=[group_id, ])
senior_student_of = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=[senior_student_of_id, ])
```

Also remove the relationship definitions from Group. Use backref to define the backref, like this:

```
    class Group(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'groups'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        group_number = Column(String(10), nullable=True, default='')
        study_hours = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=True)
        lab_studies = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=True)
        pract_studies = Column(Integer, default=0, nullable=True)

        def __repr__(self):
            return self.group_number


    class Student(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'students'
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        surname = Column(String(20), nullable=True, default='', )
        name = Column(String(20), nullable=True, default='')
        patronymic = Column(String(20), nullable=True, default='')
        absences = Column(Integer, nullable=True, default=0)
        undone_labs = Column(Integer, nullable=True, default=0)
        unready_labs = Column(Integer, nullable=True, default=0)

        group_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id))
        group = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=[group_id, ], backref="students")

        senior_student_of_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Group.id), backref="senior_student")
        senior_student_of = relationship(Group, foreign_keys=[senior_student_of_id, ])
```

I have never used the uselist=False though, so I do not know it that works.

I am not sure if this is what you really meant:

```
students = relationship('Student', backref='groups', lazy='dynamic')
```

This will put the backref groups into the Student, which means you will have Student.group**s**. But you also define Student.group in the Student class.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get group of Student (it can be only one), so I'm not sure that  ```students = relationship('Student', backref='groups', lazy='dynamic')``` would be correct to use.
Tried your solution but getting the same error, I think it's because of backref's, still not sure..

Comment: You are right. Delete the relationship definitions from Group. I updated the answer.